# Delaying jobs in laravel - Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks, jobs

so I got this code:

```
public static function postAllTasks()
{
    $allTasks = Tasks::getTasksForToday();
    foreach ($allTasks as $task) {
        $delay = DB::table('jobs')->count()*20;
        PostTasks::dispatch((string)$task->task)->delay($delay);
    }
}
```

It is working fine on my computer just fine, but as soon as it is on the server it returns the error:

> Error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Traits\curl_init() in /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/TaskTrait.php:89
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/TaskTrait.php(224)...

The problem is, that the PHP curl extension is active and visible + when I run exactly the same PHP artisan command, which doesn't use the dispatch/worker but just execute the Job (so it is using curl anyway) right away, everything works.

When I use:
**QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync**
instead of
**QUEUE_CONNECTION=database**

It works too, but I need it to use the database in order to calculate the delay between each job.

Laravel Framework 8.55.0
PHP 7.4.3

Comment: you must install php curl extension in server

Comment: apt install php7.X-curl  curl

x => version

Comment: I said that the curl extension is active and visible - means also that it is installed